# Automating an IP Phone

Tags: automation, putty, tcp, phone

I've been very interested in Automating an IP phone, currently I am automating phone calls by using PuTTY to a Dial-Up modem through simple AT commands. However, this is a poor method  because it does little beyond dialing and picking up; even worse, it can only dial certain numbers.

**What I've tried:**

I have a program that can somehow control my IP phone through my computer (too high level in the sense it doesn't have an API). Using Wireshark, I've been able to capture the packets it sends to the phone which I believe will make the command to call some number.

At this point, I thought I could send the hex values that I got from Wireshark through PuTTY using a Telnet connection. My first issue is that I'm unsure of the port number; I have tried 23 and 80 however, and in both cases: when I'm typing, the keystrokes will appear in PuTTY. That's got to be a good sign right? Unfortunately after about 20 seconds, the window closes out on its own. I've gone on the IP phone's local webpage through my browser and no information on a port number.

I can also ping the phone without specifying a port number.

**The Question:**

Can anyone explain why my PuTTY session is closing on its own and/or an alternative solution to automating an IP Phone?

Comment: All the information (port numbers, etc.) should be in the packets you captured with Wireshark. Is it TCP or UDP traffic? Which ports? The fact that PuTTY displays the characters is meaningless, as it is probably doing local echo.

Comment: Now that I take a closer look, Wireshark says the destination port is 49922, which I assume would be for the phone. Also, packets to the phone are "SKINNY" protocol, whereas returning packets are TCP.

Comment: I tried PuTTY again with 49922 as the port and it still crashes.

Comment: I doubt it matters, but you should probably be using **raw** connection type not **telnet** when connecting to a service that wasn't designed to be a telnet server.  Telnet responds to some control messages that doesn't exist in a raw TCP connection.

Comment: Port 49922 is possibly the source port. SKINNY uses port 2000.

Comment: @Zoredache Thank you for your insight; I gave TeraTerm a try and it gives a connection time out. It probably explains why PuTTY is closing.

Comment: @Ale This makes sense, I do see "Source port" as 2000 in Wireshark.

Comment: But who is initiating the connection? The phone or your PC? Look at the TCP SYN packet at the start of the conversation and check with the IP addresses who is sending it to who...

Comment: @Ale Ok, I reset everything and I found that SYN packet. The phone initializes the connection.

Comment: It looks like SCCP phones are somewhat "dumb" devices, almost everything is done on the other side of the connection. Therefore you probably need to change the SCCP server software instead of connecting to your phone...

Comment: You're right, from my research so fair, it seems that the Call Manager tells the phone exactly what to do. This seems intimidating to support myself; perhaps I'll try to find software with an API that I can interface to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the SKINNY (SCCP) protocol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skinny_Call_Control_Protocol. It is a binary protocol (as you can see in your Wireshark captures), so you can't use PuTTY to command your phone with AT-like commands. Typing hex digits in PuTTY is useless, as the data that is transmitted in the packets is not the hexadecimal digits, but the actual binary bytes. Also, resending the packets as you capture them on Wireshark is probably not working, as they contain data such as IP addresses which might not be constant, depending on your network configuration.

Comment: Looks like I have plenty of research to do. Thank you for giving me a good foundation to continue with.

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately I don't know anything about this SCCP protocol, so I can't help you more about its details...